# run multiple processes in parallel but quit together in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to create a bash script that will run multiple, long-lived scripts -- that will all be terminated with the end of the script. For example:

x.sh:

```
while :; do sleep 10 && echo '10 seconds passed'; done
```

pseduo code for y.sh:

```
./x.sh [anchored&]
./x.sh [anchored&]
./x.sh [anchored&]
```

and then in the shell, should be able to do something like:

```
$ ./y.sh
# after 10 seconds
10 seconds passed
10 seconds passed
10 seconds passed
# after another 10 seconds
10 seconds passed
10 seconds passed
10 seconds passed
^[CTRL-C]
$ # all scripts are now canceled
```

In my actual use-case, of course, I'm not running the same script (x.sh) multiple times but different commands.

Comment: Trap `SIGTERM` then send `SIGTERM` signal to all background processes.

Comment: I realized you wanted `CTRL-C`. That is `SIGINT`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a quick solution you can use.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap terminate SIGINT
terminate(){
    pkill -SIGINT -P $$
    exit
}
#the rest of your code goes here
./x.sh &
./x.sh &
wait
```

`trap` will execute the function `terminate` when `CTRL-C` is pressed. The function will execute `pkill` on all processes whose parent `PID` is the current `PID` of the script sending the signal `SIGINT`.

The `wait` at the end of the script ensures that the script remain running while children processes are running.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this one liner to your script to ensure the entire process group is killed:

```
trap "kill -- -$$" EXIT
```

Negating the scripts process id (the `-$$` part) tells kill to kill the entire process group.